# What to do against "unable to load workflow actions" error?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, error

I have a problem editing and creating new workflows with SharePoint Designer for SharePoint Online. The problem started to occur 2 days ago (The SharePoint configuration hasn't changed). The Designer seems to be working properly until I want to create/edit any workflows. Upon clicking the workflow a messeage is displayed:

> "Unable to load workflow actions from the server. Please contact your server administrator."

I tried:

- Reinstalling the designer and deleting the cache.
- Using another user to start the designer (as SharePoint Admim).
- Creating a new workflow (fails).

Workflows uploaded before the error are working fine.

Does anybody know about this problem or what I could try? Currently thinking about creating a ticket since I do not have access to ULS logs (SharePoint Online).

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of this question. The problem is resolved right now. It had to do with the SP Online servers. There was an incident report in the O365-Panel shortly after posting this question.